# Scala Default parameter value derived from previous parameters

Tags: scala

Is there any way to do something like this

```
class Foo (val bar:Any, val baz:Any = magic(bar))
```

without overloading constructor or making `baz` mutable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use different parameter groups:

```
def test(i: Int)(j: Int = i + 1) = i + j
test(1)()
// Int = 3

class Foo (val bar: Int)(val baz: Int = bar + 1)
new Foo(1)().baz
// Int = 2
```

For constructors you could also use `None` for default value of constructor parameter and then define `val` in class body:

```
class Foo (val bar: Int, _baz: Option[Int] = None) {
  val baz = _baz.getOrElse(bar + 1)
}
new Foo(1).baz
// Int = 2
```

Note that for `case class` you can't use different parameter groups (if you want to get all parameters in `unapply`) nor class body. The only way is to define an addition `apply` method in companion object.